# Oracle SQL Automation

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I have a question regarding Automation.In my project we have 35 SQL scripts  with same logic,same scripts for all those, with only 4 parameters different how can i automate these in TOAD for Oracle?

Comment: I dont know about toad automation , but i would suggest instead of toad why dont you use crontab from terminal.

Comment: Did you check DBMS_SCHEDULER (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#CIHDJEEB) or isn't that an option?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of Toad, there could be a 'Automation Designer' under the 'Utilities' menu item. This will allow you to run scripts automatically, based on a bit of logic. It also supports running with parameters.

The tool 'Toad for Data Analysts' can also be used to model automated scripts, and run them with specific parameters.

If you have any of these tools available, I would suggest giving them a try, or at least read up on their documentation. If you don't have access to these, let me know so I can try and think of a different solution.